# Android button on card view, get position of card view on click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I've got a card-view that each card has a button on it. I'm trying to get the position of the card that holds the button when the users clicks the button.

I have an adapter that extends from RecyclerView.Adapter and implements the following method...

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieImageViewHolder movieImageViewHolder, int i) {
    Movie movieItem = mMovieList.get(i);

    movieImageViewHolder.details.setTag(i);
    movieImageViewHolder.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        }
    });
}
```

This works sucessfully, when I press a button on card 1, position equals 1 and when I press a button on card 4, position equals 4.

The question is, how do I get this value (position) out of the adapter and back into the Activity so I can use it? or do I even need to do that? I'm trying to create a new intent but don't think that should be done from the adapter?

I attempted to create a getter for the variable position, and call the primary button action with

```
 public void buttonClick(View view) {
    int position = adapter.getPosition();
    Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked::- " + String.valueOf(position));
}
```

Using

```
android:onClick="buttonClick"
```

In the XML, but nothing happens when clicking the button, I believe this is because the OnClick method in the adapter is fired instead?

EDIT:

Seems I've made some progress. Worked out that I can set the tag in the adapter

```
movieImageViewHolder.btn_details.setTag(i);
```

Then get that tag back in my onClick method with .getTag();

Only thing now is the tag seems to be zero for the first element, then zero for the second element, then starts at one for the third... Any reason why this would be?

Comment: are you getting `Button Clicked:` in log?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No, hence my comment around if it's only being called from the adapter instead.

Comment: In which Button you are adding `buttonClick` listener and when you want to get `position` out of Adapter ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: I mean in which Button you are adding `buttonClick` onClick method? and when you want to get `position` of clicked button in Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I'm adding it to the same button that implements the listener in the adapter.

Comment: when you want to get `position` of clicked button in Activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70450/discussion-between-peavers-and--k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually very simple and a very common "issue" people face. I was set down the path that I couldn't create an activity from an adapter where infact that is exactly what I should have been trying to do.

```
 movieImageViewHolder.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            Integer taggedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ViewMovieDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(SearchMovie.MOVIE_TRANSFER, getMovie(taggedPosition));
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Correctly starts the correct activity.